# Running JUnit tests with Ant

Tags: java, testing, ant, build, junit

I am trying to run my JUnit test cases, but I keep getting the error :

```
Test com.capscan.accentsWorld FAILED
```

The report is created, but the test aren't run. Here is my Ant code:

```
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
<target name="create_run_jar">

    <fail if="testsfailed" message="tests failed" /> 
    <delete dir="outputs/reports" />
    <mkdir dir="outputs/reports" />

    <junit printsummary="on" errorproperty="testsfailed">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.com.capscan.accentsWorld}"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>

        <formatter type="plain"/>

        <test name="com.capscan.accentsWorld" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
        </test>

        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="src/com/capscan/accentsWorld/" >
            <fileset dir="src/com/capscan/accentsWorld/">
                <include name="**/Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml" />
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="outputs/reports">
        <fileset dir="outputs/reports">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="outputs/reports" />
    </junitreport>

</target>
```

and here is the output message on my console:

```
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\Ergun Polat\Desktop\Erguns Content\workspace\AccentsWorld\build.xml
create_run_jar:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Documents and Settings\Ergun Polat\Desktop\Erguns Content\workspace\AccentsWorld\outputs\reports
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Documents and Settings\Ergun Polat\Desktop\Erguns Content\workspace\AccentsWorld\outputs\reports
    [junit] Running com.capscan.accentsWorld
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.capscan.accentsWorld FAILED
[junitreport] Processing C:\Documents and Settings\Ergun Polat\Desktop\Erguns Content\workspace\AccentsWorld\outputs\reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\DOCUME~1\ERGUNP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\null1982495120
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 1047ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\DOCUME~1\ERGUNP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\null1982495120
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: Take a look at the reports. There will be more information there.

Comment: Test isnt ran so only information is shown is nothing

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any `<javac>` task to compile the tests.  Don't you have to do that first?

And I'm not sure where you think `java.class.path` is coming from, but I'd set it explicitly inside your Ant build.xml

Here's a generic build.xml that I use, including the testing task.  Give it a look and see if it can help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="xslt-converter" basedir="." default="package">

    <property name="version" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="haltonfailure" value="no"/>

    <property name="out" value="out"/>

    <property name="production.src" value="src"/>
    <property name="production.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="production.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="production.classes" value="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="test.src" value="test"/>
    <property name="test.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="test.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="test.classes" value="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="exploded" value="out/exploded/${ant.project.name}"/>
    <property name="exploded.classes" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="exploded.lib" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/lib"/>

    <property name="reports.out" value="${out}/reports"/>
    <property name="junit.out" value="${reports.out}/junit"/>
    <property name="testng.out" value="${reports.out}/testng"/>

    <path id="production.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.class.path">                            
        <path refid="production.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <include name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="testng.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/testng*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <available file="${out}" property="outputExists"/>

    <target name="clean" description="remove all generated artifacts" if="outputExists">
        <delete dir="${out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
        <delete dir="${reports.out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="create" description="create the output directories" unless="outputExists">
        <mkdir dir="${production.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${reports.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${junit.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${testng.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.lib}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile all .java source files" depends="create">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="production.class.path" refid="production.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${production.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="production.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit-test" description="run all junit tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${haltonfailure}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.out}">
                <fileset dir="${test.src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <junitreport todir="${junit.out}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.out}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${junit.out}" format="frames"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="testng.class.path"/>
    <target name="testng-test" description="run all testng tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <testng classpathref="test.class.path" outputDir="${testng.out}" haltOnFailure="${haltonfailure}" verbose="2" parallel="methods" threadcount="50">
            <classfileset dir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

    <target name="exploded" description="create exploded deployment" depends="testng-test">
        <copy todir="${exploded.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${production.classes}"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${exploded.lib}">
            <fileset dir="${production.lib}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="package" description="create package file" depends="exploded">
        <jar destfile="${out}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${production.classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What did you do with it?  It runs my tests just fine.  Did you look at it?  It's certainly different from yours - did you try to understand what's different and see if it explains why yours is failing?  If you just take mine and try to run it, you do understand that you'll have to at least understand the directory structure it's using an make yours match it, right?

Comment: I've looked at yours and do understand the directory structure which is why i am trying to apply it to my own.

Comment: I know mine runs JUnit tests.  If it's not working for you, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the ant in a verbose mode (`ant -v`). You should see more information.

Maybe you are missing something that is really basic like the `@Test` annotation in your test class (it happend to me that I only had methods annotated with `@Ignore`), or you have an error in a classpath. Show us fragment of your test class.