# Build.xml configuration for running JUnit Tests using Ant

Tags: java, xml, junit, ant

I'm trying to use `ant -v` to build a `JAR` file from the command line but I keep receiving the following error message:

`BUILD FAILED
MyApp/build.xml:73: The <classpath> or <modulepath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath`

The directory structure is as follows:

`.
├── bin
|   └── packageOne
|   └── packageTwo
|   └── packageThree
├── dist
├── docs
|   ├── [All Generated Java Docs]
├── lib
|   ├── junit-4.11.jar
|   └── org.hamcrest.core_1.3.jar
├── src
|   ├── [All Source Files In Their Package]
├── test
|   ├── [All JUnit Tests in One Package]
├── testreport
|   ├── [Would like test report to be created here]
├── build.xml`

The contents of `build.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyApp" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
    <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />

    <!-- Variables used for JUnit testing -->
    <property name="test.dir" location="test" />
    <property name="test.report.dir" location="testreport" />

    <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creates the build, docs and dist directory -->
    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Create a classpath container which can be later used in the ant task -->
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
            <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
    <target name="docs" depends="compile">
        <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
            <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
             <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
             </fileset>
        </javadoc>
    </target>

    <!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling -->
    <path id="junit.class.path">
        <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.11.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
    </path>

    <!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
        <!-- Output is XML, could also be plain -->
        <target name="junit" depends="compile">
            <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
                    <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
                <formatter type="xml" />
                <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </target>

    <!-- Creates the deployable jar file -->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\MyApp.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyApp.Main" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="compile, docs, junit, jar">
        <description>Main target</description>
    </target>

</project>
```

I've been following the [Apache Ant tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html#junit4) which features an example of a JUnit `build.xml` but no matter where I place my JUnit `.jar` files, I still receive the same error.

In addition, I've found multiple SO answers that suggest the problem lies with my build.xml, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923861/classnotfound-exception-when-running-junit-test-from-build-xml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518677/running-junit-tests-with-ant).

The full verbose error message is:

```
build.xml:64: The <classpath> or <modulepath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.createMirror(JUnitTask.java:785)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.setupJUnitDelegate(JUnitTask.java:832)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:845)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:469)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1370)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:849)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:228)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.Test
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1089)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.SplitClassLoader.loadClass(SplitClassLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.createMirror(JUnitTask.java:780)
    ... 18 more

Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: The directory structure you posted indicates that you have a file named `junit-4.11.jar` in the lib directory but `junit.class.path` specifically points to `junit.jar`

Comment: Updated my code and OP but the error still persists - I copied the local JAR files from `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins` and renamed them to match another SO answer